# problem executing Javascript from a python cgi

Tags: javascript, python, cgi

I'm running a Python program on a server and want to provide a client side interface.  I'm using a simple web server (from the O'Reilly Programming Python book).

I can generate HTML pages without problems.  However now I want to generate a page which includes some JavaScript to validate user input on the client before returning it to the python application on the server.  The problematic part of the python code is:

```
htmlcode = """
`<head`>  ## Heading ##
    `<title`>PAROT - Report Options`</title`>  
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="FormChecks.js"`>
    `</script`>

`</head`>
`<body`>
    `<form method=POST action="cgiRunQuery.py"`>"""'
```

When I send this to the server, it complains:

```
tclogin1 - - [08/Dec/2010 10:55:02] "GET /cgi-bin/FormChecks.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/CGIHTTPServer.py", line 255, in run_cgi
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, os.environ)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
tclogin1 - - [08/Dec/2010 10:55:02] CGI script exit status 0x7f00
```

It looks as though the python is trying to execute the JavaScript.  If I create a static html page containing the generated html code (including JavaScript), it all works fine.

Comment: How are you "sending this to the server"?

Answer (score 3):

Your web server thinks that `FormChecks.js` is meant to be executed as a CGI script, which of course it's not. Move it outside of `cgi-bin/` and change the path in your `script` tag accordingly. You could also try removing the executable bit from it instead.

Answer (score 0):

What are all those backticks for?

The error seems to be simply that you've got an extra single quote at the end of your closing triple-quote.

Comment: They're probably something to indicate to a primitive HTML generation engine that the characters should not be encoded before sending.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly. thanks all for taking the time to answer-

I had to but all the back ticks in or else Stack Overflow wouldn't display my HTML code.

If I remove the FormCheck.js from the cgi-bin directory, I get the following from the webserver:

tclogin1 - - [08/Dec/2010 12:42:17] "POST /cgi-bin/cgiGetReportOptions.py HTTP/1.1" 200 -
tclogin1 - - [08/Dec/2010 12:42:17] code 404, message No such CGI script ('/cgi-bin/FormChecks.js')
tclogin1 - - [08/Dec/2010 12:42:17] "GET /cgi-bin/FormChecks.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

The server is seeing the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="FormChecks.js">
```

and for some reason trying to run the javascript file as CGI script

Arghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh!!!

I've played around some more and the problem was:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/FormChecks.js">
```

I was missing the "/" before FormChecks.js.

Thanks for all the suggestions - on to solving the next problem now :-)

Comment: This is a comment. Please don't "answer" your own question with a comment. Just update the original.